# Do two SCHED_FIFO tasks with equal priority get processing time within each period in Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduler, scheduling, cfs

Do two SCHED_FIFO tasks with equal priority get processing time within each period in Linux, granted neither of the tasks finish before the period ends?

Linux documentation says SCHED_FIFO processes can get preempted only by processes with higher priority, but my understanding is that CFS operates on a higher layer, and assigns timeslots to each of the two tasks within each period.

Comment: If you want them to have same priority and equal processing time, you can use `SCHED_RR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Linux documentation says SCHED_FIFO processes can get preempted only by processes with higher priority

This is correct, in addition to this, they can also be preempted if you set `RLIMIT_RTTIME` (`getrlimit(2)`) and that limit is reached.

The only other reasons why another `SCHED_FIFO` process (with the same priority) can be scheduled is if the first *sleeps* or if it *voluntary yields* (voluntary preemption).

[CFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt) has nothing to do with `SCHED_FIFO`, it only takes care of `SCHED_NORMAL`, `SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE`.